# An error occurs when 'exportfs -a' is entered

Tags: server, mount, nfs

How's it going?I'm using ubuntu14.04.

- First,`sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common`.
- Second,`sudo gedit /etc/exports`,and add the lines:
  `# Share 'roach_boot' directory/srv/roach_boot 192.168.100.0/24(rw,subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure)`
- The last,`exportfs -a`
- At this time, the terminal displays:
  `sandang@wz-sandang:/etc$ sudo exportfs -a`

`exportfs: No options for to NFS: suggest NFS(sync) to avoid warning`

`exportfs: /etc/exports [1]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "NFS:to".`

`Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').`

`NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x`

May I ask what are the reasons for these?
I would be really appreciated if you reply!
Wang

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: search for `no_subtree_check` in `man exports`